# writing Log files to Database using talend

Tags: talend

[This is the actual Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpRa3.png)I am having job which executes log files as output. I am doing this using tLogRow, but I want to write them into Database, Is that possible with talend? I have already used tMysqlRow and tMysqlOutput but those are throwing some errors. I have searched in google but there isn't any clear answer for this.
[This is the actual output when using TlogRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3HWr.png)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Albin I have added the error . This error occurs with tMySqlOutput component

Comment: Check your table columns, is there any column named "priority"?

Comment: @Albin Thankyou, i have removed those errors, but I want to write the table into mysql Db and the component is compiling without any error but isn't writing into Db. I have attached the image of actual output in the question.

Comment: Can you put your job screen shot here?

Comment: @Albin I have added the actual job in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the error information directly from tLogCatcher to database table. Please make sure that table name and column names from table should match the tMysqlOutput schema. if you don't want to save the complete information, you can use a tXmlMap for filter the columns required.

[image]